# Animate color value of VisualBrush on MouseEnter / MouseLeave (WPF)

Tags: wpf, storyboard, jquery-animate

I have the following problem. I am looking to animate the color value of an icon on mouseover (and animate it back once the mouse has left). To achieve this I have created a new ColorAnimation which is triggered on MouseEnter. The property path of the animation is "(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)". But when running this gives the error; *'Fill' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)'*. While I think I understand what the error means, I have no idea what property path I should use. Any ideas? Thank you in advance for your time. Please let me know if anything is left unclear.

Ps. If anyone has a better idea on how to place 'icon / path' resources I am much obliged.

Code;

```
ColorAnimation mouseEnterColorAnimation = new ColorAnimation {
  To = Colors.Yellow,
  Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
};

Storyboard.SetTargetName(mouseEnterColorAnimation, "DeleteIconGrid");
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(mouseEnterColorAnimation, new PropertyPath("Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"));
Storyboard mouseEnterStoryboard = new Storyboard();
mouseEnterStoryboard.Children.Add(mouseEnterColorAnimation);
mouseEnterStoryboard.Begin(this);
```

Xaml;

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="Transparent" Width="100" Height="100" MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown" MouseEnter="Grid_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Grid_MouseLeave" >
  <Grid x:Name="DeleteIconGrid" Width="50" Margin="0,0,0,14"><Grid.Background><VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource Icon-Delete}" Stretch="Uniform" /></Grid.Background></Grid>
  <Label Content="Delete icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="6" Foreground="{DynamicResource Gray}"></Label>
</Grid>
```

Resources;

```
<Canvas x:Key="Icon-Delete" Background="Transparent">
  <Path Stretch="Uniform" Fill="LightSlateGray" Data="F1 M 4.70432,0L 0.0480347,4.77802L 7.00842,11.6812L 0,18.7292L 4.70432,23.46L 11.6647,16.412L 18.6252,23.46L 23.3774,18.7774L 16.369,11.6812L 23.3294,4.77802L 18.6252,0L 11.6647,6.9986L 4.70432,0 Z" />
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `VisualBrush` does *not* have a `Color` property... you seem to be confusing it with a `SolidColorBrush`. Therefore you cannot animate the colour of a `VisualBrush` but you can when using a `SolidColorBrush`.

You also have a mistake in your `PropertyPath`... instead of this:

```
"Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
```

it should be this:

```
"(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
```

Finally, if you want to animate the `Color` property of a `Brush` then you'll need to set the `Fill` property to an instance of `SolidColorBrush` like you did in the `Path` in the `Canvas`:

```
<Path Stretch="Uniform" Fill="LightSlateGray" Data="F1 M 4.70432,0L 0.0480347,4.77802L 7.00842,11.6812L 0,18.7292L 4.70432,23.46L 11.6647,16.412L 18.6252,23.46L 23.3774,18.7774L 16.369,11.6812L 23.3294,4.77802L 18.6252,0L 11.6647,6.9986L 4.70432,0 Z" />
```

---

UPDATE >>>

In order to animate a `VisualBrush.Visual`, you will need to declare it inline. Take this example from the [VisualBrush Animation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9a953d11-d866-4482-8e9c-c1b446f25ddb/visualbrush-animation) page on the Visual Studio Forum:

```
<Button Width="320" Height="240">
    <Button.Background>
        <VisualBrush>
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Canvas>
                    <Rectangle Width="320" Height="240" Name="myRect" Fill="Blue">
                        <Rectangle.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                                            <Storyboard >
                                                <ColorAnimation To="Red" Duration="0:0:2" Storyboard.TargetName="myRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger.Actions>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Rectangle.Triggers>
                    </Rectangle>
                </Canvas>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thank you Sheridan for your reply. If I understand you correctly, you state that since a VisualBrush does not have a Color property I should animate the SolidColorBrush itself. But that is exactly what I target with my PropertyPath right? ("(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)")

Should I target a different property?

Comment: You cannot target a `SolidColorBrush.Color` property when using a `VisualBrush`. `VisualBrush` colours cannot be animated unless you actually animate the `Visual` of the `VisualProperty`.

Comment: So that means I should target the Visual of the VisualProperty instead? How would I target the color property of the Visual through a PropertyPath?

Comment: Since my Storyboard targets 'DeleteIconGrid', I expected the following PropertyPath to work, but it doesn't for some reason; `PropertyPath("(Background.VisualBrush.Visual.Fill.Color)")`. Any idea what PropertyPath I should use? Thanks!